# Number of users required to approve a suggested edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Why suggested edits on Stack Overflow need to be approved by 3 users while in other websites such as Information Security, only 2 users must approve an edit?

Comment: We have a lot more eyeballs to look at them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Information Security is not Stack Overflow. It's SE2.0.

Stack Overflow receives *an order of magnitude more traffic* than any other Stack Exchange site, and about half of the network's total traffic. SO can *easily* provide one additional review for each suggested edit because it has so many 2k users.

Except for tag wiki edits. I hate how long those take.

Answer (score 3):

It's historical. It used to be a single vote. But then the /review page was changed from its old form to the current system. Suddenly there was a lot of robo-reviewing. In response to this, the number of required reviewers for edits was quickly raised to two, and three on Stack Overflow.

Source: [It takes two to tango?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151536/it-takes-two-to-tango/151586#151586)

The reason that Stack Overflow required three isn't specified, but it's in all likeliness that SO is the biggest site on the network. It was probably hoped that three people would make a better judgment than two, and SO had the scale to make this feasible.

Comment: it's two now, which is really bad. very bad edits that completely break posts are routinely getting approved ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21367700)).