# Why was the required number of reviews to approve/reject a suggested edit changed from 3 to 2?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I noticed that on Stack Overflow, there are some very old suggested edits that took 3 reviews to approve/reject ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2895307)). However, all the more recent reviews I've seen only took 2 reviews to finalize. Apparently it used to take 3 reviews because [there were enough users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337710/number-of-users-required-to-approve-a-suggested-edit/337713#337713) with 2k reputation to review them quickly.

When and why was it changed to require 2 reviews instead of 3?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Due to the top bar redesign, the suggested edits queue was getting full because people were reviewing less. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349125/6083675)'s what Shog said in an answer on  May 13 2017 when he made the change:

> [T]here's no particular need for the number of reviews per edit to remain at 3 on Stack Overflow; reducing this should *immediately* speed up the process of reviewing edits, and thus alleviate the problem at hand. So I've done that - **effective immediately, suggested edits require only 2 reviews to complete on Stack Overflow**, just as they do elsewhere on the network.